# Facebook open graph debugger : error 200 : can't download

Tags: facebook, debugging, http-status-code-403, facebook-sharer, scraper

I'm having trouble using the Facebook sharer with my site [www.moncorpsetmoi.com](http://www.moncorpsetmoi.com).
The debugger says `Can't download: Could not retrieve data from URL.`

Any help, any ideas?

Comment: I already tried with an absolute URL, and I added open graph meta tags, the result is the same... 
Any site, without any point of the "facebook sharing checklist" is well shared. The (BIG) probleme is that it is impossible to share THIS site with sharer.php... Why ? 
Please, is there a facebook developer to help me ?? x)

Comment: It seems to be ok now in the facebook debugger (you can try it), but the facebook sharer.php still doesn't work ! I hope it is because of the cache of the facebook sharer. Thanks for your help

Comment: The facebook sharer.php still doesn't work with the front page of the site www.moncorpsetmoi.com. Any idea, help ? Thanks

Comment: I solve this probleme by adding "/index.php" to the url to share. But why a blank page when sharing the url without "/index.php" ?

Answer (score 0):

At first I think that, for sharer.php, you should include an absolute URL, (including http://)
In addition, I can't see any OpenGraph meta tags in your page, debugger is trying to retrieve page information by looking for these meta tags, whose - in your case - are not present, and results an error message.
see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/checklist/

Comment: En fait j'ai bien sûr essayé en URL absolue ou non, le résultat et le même.
J'ai également ajouté les metas open graph sur toutes les pages du site, cela ne change rien.

Comment: I already tried with an absolute URL, and I added open graph meta tags, the result is the same... 
Any site, without any point of the "facebook sharing checklist" is well shared. The (BIG) probleme is that it is impossible to share THIS site with sharer.php... Why ? 
Please, is there a facebook developer to help me ?? x)

Comment: you should also modify the opening <html> tag namespace/prefix:
xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"
That should solve your main issue.

also, og:type, og:url, og:title, og:image are required tags, og:image is missing in your case. While facebook can replace missing / small images, this might result in an error/warning.

You should also provide an fb:app_id, or at least an fb:admins tag with your own facebook userid, if don't have an app id yet.

http://ogp.me/

Comment: It seems to be ok now in the facebook debugger (you can try it), but the facebook sharer.php still doesn't work ! I hope it is because of the cache of the facebook sharer. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: The facebook sharer.php still doesn't work with the front page of the site www.moncorpsetmoi.com. Any idea, help ? Thanks

Comment: I solve this probleme by adding "/index.php" to the url to share. But why a blank page when sharing the url without "/index.php" ?